# Accessing a Shared Server with Backslashes in the Address via Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, escaping, backslash

I've been struggling to get Express to work with a shared server looking like this:

```
53.165.137.28\NAME,94273
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to connect to 53.165.137.28:undefined in 15000ms
```

I tried escaping using double backslashes "\\", but it doesn't work. Also, using %5C also didn't work.

**Note:**
I can query this server via SQL Server Management Studio just fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

Instead of this:

```
var dbCofing = {
    user: 'USER',
    password: 'PASS',
    server: '53.165.137.28\\NAME,94273',
    database: 'DATABASE'
}
```

I used the following:

```
var dbCofing = {
    user: 'USER',
    password: 'PASS',
    server: '53.165.137.28',
    instanceName: 'NAME',
    port: 94273,
    database: 'DATABASE'
}
```